# JavaScript appendChild() not working? (first time with appendChild())

Tags: javascript, appendchild

I am trying to build a little resume builder. I want the user to be able to enter any number of phone numbers. However, the appendChild() is not working as expected. Actually, it's not working at all. It does nothing. Any ideas?

HTML:

```
<div id="phoneNumbers">
    <?php 
    if(isset($_SESSION['phoneNumber'])){
        for($i = 0; $i<sizeof($_SESSION['phoneNumber']); $i++){
            echo "<input type=\"text\" size=\"20\" name = \"phoneNumber[".$i."]\" 
                    value=\"".$_SESSION['phoneNumber'][$i]."\" />
                  <br />"; 
        }

    }
    else{
    ?>

    <input type="text" size="20" name = "phoneNumber[0]" 
        value="" />
    <br /> 

    <?php   
    }
    ?>

</div>


<input type="button" value="Add another phone number" onclick="addPhoneNumber()">
```

Javascript:

```
var numberOfPhoneInputs = 1;

function addPhoneNumber()
{

// Found out the following doesn't work as expected...
//  var newPhoneNumberInput =  "<input type=\"text\" size=\"20\" name = \"phoneNumber[" + 
//      numberOfPhoneInputs +"]\" value=\"\" />" +
//    "<br />" 
//  document.getElementById("phoneNumbers").innerHTML += newPhoneNumberInput;


    var div = document.getElementByID("phoneNumbers");

    var newPhoneNumberInput = document.createElement('input');
    newPhoneNumberInput.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    newPhoneNumberInput.setAttribute('name', 'phoneNumber['+numberOfPhoneInputs+']');
    newPhoneNumberInput.setAttribute('size', '20');
    newPhoneNumberInput.setAttribute('value', '');
    div.appendChild(newPhoneNumberInput);


    numberOfPhoneInputs ++;
}
```

Comment: You have an XSS vulnerability.

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementByID` needs to be  `document.getElementById`

This error should show in your console.

Comment: Thanks! I don't have any console... :(

Comment: @Silver: Use Firebug or Chrome.  Developing without a console is like driving without windows.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `return false;` from the click handler to prevent the button's default action of submitting the page.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make these changes ...

1. change `document.getElementByID("phoneNumbers");` to `document.getElementById("phoneNumbers");`
2. (optional) It will be good if you change `var div` to `var phoneNumbersDiv` or something

**fiddle example :** http://jsfiddle.net/v8rF3/

**Updated code:**

```
var numberOfPhoneInputs = 1;

function addPhoneNumber(){
    var div1 = document.getElementById("phoneNumbers");
    var newPhoneNumberInput = document.createElement('input');
    newPhoneNumberInput.setAttribute('type', 'text');           newPhoneNumberInput.setAttribute('name', 'phoneNumber['+numberOfPhoneInputs+']');
    newPhoneNumberInput.setAttribute('size', '20');
    newPhoneNumberInput.setAttribute('value', '');
    div1.appendChild(newPhoneNumberInput);

    numberOfPhoneInputs ++;
}
```

Comment: There's no reason I can think of why he needs to change `var div` to `var div1`, can you elaborate?

Comment: not necessary.. updated the code.. i just said for better purpose since div is a element name.